# Raspberry Pi Neopixel "Selected GPIO not possible"

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, adafruit-circuitpython, neopixel

I'm using an Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.2 to control an RGB-Ringlight with Python using the Neopixel library. I'm getting the error message: *ws2811_init failed with code -11 (Selected GPIO not possible)*
My code is:

```
LightMode.CONTROLLER = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D1,LED_COUNT,brightness=1,pixel_order=neopixel.GRB,auto_write=True,bpp=3)
LightMode.CONTROLLER.fill((0,0,0))
```

gpio readall tells me BCM Pin 18 is GPIO 1 so I set the pin to 1

Answer (score -1):

Found the error. NeoPixel uses the Board Pin numbers, not GPIO numbers.